# Does not respond to Discord Interaction

Tags: discord

I recently saw the new updates on bot, and the components feature. After looking at Discord API, I saw you can ACK an Interaction, and directly reply to it, or delay if the Interaction involves a long process. The issue I have is with Slash Commands : if you choose to simply ACK the Interaction, the client will display "[Application] is thinking...". I don't want this message to appear (because I either don't want feedback from certain commands or do it with another way).

The only workaround I found yet is to send a ACK and directly delete it after. But it is still making a notification for other people. I tried using ephemeral messages, but I haven't found a way to force the client to dismiss it.
I know these features are recent, and maybe some part are not entirely documented, so i'm asking if someone know a way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I haven't found anything since, I'll conclude it is not possible yet.